# Probability that the Mets, Jets, and Knicks all win in consecutive seasons

Tags: probability

> If the New York Mets have won $2$ titles in $58$ years, the New York Jets have won $1$ title in $60$ years, and the New York Knicks have won $2$ titles in $73$ years, what is the probability that they all won in the span of two consecutive years?

My (very sleep-deprived) analysis ran along these lines: First of all, the probability that all win in the same season is $\frac{2}{73}\times \frac{1}{60}\times \frac{2}{58}\times 58$, the extra $\times 58$ because it could have happened any of the $58$ years all three teams have existed. That probability is about 0.09 percent. The numbers get slightly more interesting when you involve consecutive years. Assume two of them win in year $N$, and the third wins in year $N+1$. Then the probability for that is $\frac{2}{73}\times \frac{1}{60}\times \frac{2}{58}\times 57$, because one of the years all three teams have existed (the last one) cannot have played a year $N+1$ year. This is mirrored in two of them having been the year after one wins. Thus the percentage probability overall is $100(\frac{2}{73}\times \frac{1}{60}\times \frac{2}{58}\times 58+ 2\times (\frac{2}{73}\times \frac{1}{60}\times \frac{2}{58}\times 57))$ approximately equals 0.27 percent.

However, I’m almost certain I made several mistakes, and I’d appreciate a more rigorous (and correct) analysis.

Comment: Can multiple teams even win the title in the same season? I believe there can be a maximum of one winner per season. Please clarify.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb I believe these are disjoint sports, so they can win independently of each other.

Comment: Ah ok did not realise. Thanks @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Mets plays in baseball, Knicks in basketball, Jets in American football.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll assume that you meant to imply that since we don’t know when the titles were actually won, we should regard all possible combinations of years as equiprobable. I’ll also assume that the three spans of years are in each case the most recent years, so that their overlap consists of the last $58$ years.

You can do this using [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

For any given one of the last $57$ spans of $2$ consecutive years, the probability that all three teams won a title in one of those $2$ years is

$$
\left(1-\frac{\binom{56}2}{\binom{58}2}\right)\left(1-\frac{\binom{58}1}{\binom{60}1}\right)\left(1-\frac{\binom{71}2}{\binom{73}2}\right)=\frac{16159}{130322520}\;.
$$

For the span of $2$ consecutive years before that, the probability is different, since the Mets didn't exist in the first of those two years:

$$
\left(1-\frac{\binom{57}2}{\binom{58}2}\right)\left(1-\frac{\binom{58}1}{\binom{60}1}\right)\left(1-\frac{\binom{71}2}{\binom{73}2}\right)=\frac{143}{2286360}\;.
$$

We have to add these two contributions, but then we have to subtract the cases that we double-counted, where each team won a title in $2$ consecutive spans of $2$ consecutive years. (Since the Jets only won one title, we don’t need to consider spans further apart.)

Again, we treat the $56$ cases of $2$ spans of $2$ consecutive years for which the Mets existed throughout all $3$ years first. For each team to have won a title in both spans, the Jets must have won their title in the middle year, and the other two teams must have won a title either in the middle year or in any two of the three years. The probability for this is

$$
\left(\frac{\binom{55}1+\binom32}{\binom{58}2}\right)\cdot\frac1{60}\cdot\left(\frac{\binom{70}1+\binom32}{\binom{73}2}\right)=\frac1{61560}\;.
$$

And again we have to treat the $2$ consecutive spans of $2$ consecutive years for which the Mets didn’t exist in the first of the $3$ years separately:

$$
\left(\frac{\binom{56}1+\binom22}{\binom{58}2}\right)\cdot\frac1{60}\cdot\left(\frac{\binom{70}1+\binom32}{\binom{73}2}\right)=\frac1{62640}\;.
$$

Then by inclusion–exclusion the overall probability for there to be at least one span of $2$ consecutive years in which all three teams won a title is

$$
57\cdot\frac{16159}{130322520}+\frac{143}{2286360}-56\cdot\frac1{61560}-\frac1{62640}=\frac{1617163}{260645040}\approx0.620\%\;.
$$

The main error in your calculation is that in your second term you missed a factor of $3$ that arises because where you have one team winning in one year and two in the other, each of the three teams could be the one that wins in the one year. If you include that factor of $3$, you get

$$
\frac2{73}\cdot\frac1{60}\cdot\frac2{58}\cdot(58+2\cdot3\cdot57)=\frac{40}{6351}\approx0.630\%\;,
$$

which is off by only one-hundredth of a percent – this remaining discrepancy is because of some of the fine points and the double-counting that you ignored.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, they dont paly the same sport

Comment: @fruitbat: That seems to be a misunderstanding. I didn't assume that they play the same sport. Please point out where you thought that assumption is made.